# Regex allow ; and at least 5 digit numbers and trim leading/trailing semicolon in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

This is what I am after:

Replace all characters that are not digits and not semicolon ; with nothing: "".
Numbers must be at least 5 digits long.
Trim leading and trailing semicolon ;

So:
567834 is valid
123456;654321;3456789 is valid
123;456 is not valid(too short numbers), will be replaced with empty string ""
;123456; will be trimmed to 123456
;567890 will be trimmed to 567890
456789; will be trimmed to 456789

I was thinking of using replaceAll method to do the work.

```
str.replaceAll("(\\d+\\;?)*\\d+", "");
```

But this doesn't take care of trimming leading and trailing semicolons and doesn't replace too short numbers with "".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend breaking the problem into steps.  This is an easy problem if you do.  A single regex will be challenging, both to develop today and to read for every day after.  Readable, easily understandable code should be your objective.

```
String trimmedStr = str.trim();
String noSemicolons = trimmedStr.replaceAll(";", "");
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^\d{5,}$").matcher(noSemicolons);
boolean isValid = matcher.matches();
```

Comment: +1 for "Readable, easily understandable code should be your objective." Especially for regex: Not everybody in a team is a regex guru. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll(";?\\b(\\d{5,})\\b;?|[\\d;]*", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG2vQ9/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this replacement:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("(\\d{5,})|\\d{1,4}(?:;+|\\z)|;+\\d{0,4}\\z|\\A;", "$1");
```

The idea is to preserve numbers with at least 5 digits first in a capture group *(because the first branch on the left that succeeds wins)*. Other branches describes what you need to remove.

An other way:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("((?:\\d{5,}(?:;(?!\\z))?)*+)(?:;*\\d{0,4}(?:;+|\\z))++", "$1");
```

This one describes the string as a succession of parts to remove preceded by an optional part to preserve.